# ASP.NET MEmbership Lockout for 30minutes

Tags: asp.net

Greetings,

In ASP.NET, is there a way to lockout the members for 30 minutes (or given period) if they enter the password for 5 times?

This asswordAnswerAttemptLockoutDuration, won't work for me. I'm after actual invalid password entry.

Thanks Heaps.

Comment: can you provide me a link to your answer and see if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is only valid for an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.

You could set the [MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx)- and the [PasswordAttempWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.passwordattemptwindow.aspx) properties. Then f.e. after 5 invalid passwords the user will be locked by setting the [IsLockedOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.islockedout.aspx) property to true and can be unlocked by the [UnlockUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.unlockuser.aspx) method.

You could compare the `FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart` value with `DateTime.Now` to check if the user could be unlocked and logged in again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't implement this feature. Although it may look like a good security idea, it actually isn't. Because with this, I can easily lock any user I want, I just need to know his login name.

Comment: I think in a intranet environment it could make sense to avoid brute force attacks(f.e. from outside the intranet). Anyway, your inversion of an argument doesn't make much sense. Because this feature could be abused, it isn't a security feature at all?!

Comment: How can it be a security feature if it can be abused? If it can be abused, I call it a security flaw actually. But I agree with the intranet point.

Answer (score 1):

We've implemented a feature similar to this a while back, and works pretty well. I haven't got the code on me, but it went something like this.

On the login page, have a function that determines if the user trying to login is locked out of the system and if that user has been locked out for less than x amount of minutes display an error message, else unlock them and proceed with the login.

Hope that makes sense, I'll try and dig the code out on Monday when I'm back in the office if you need it.

Comment: I wish you had dug out that code on Monday. I think it's kinda late now, it's been 13 years